# Reusing String in C++ in function

Tags: c++, string, c++17

As someone whose main language has been Python so far, I have a problem with string reuse.

Here's an example code (simplified):

```
void function(std::string &basicString) 
{
std::cout << "Function print: " << &basicString << "\n";
}

int main() 
{
std::vector<std::string> x_files;
/*
Does sth, x_files contains some strings
*/

for (std::vector<std::string>::size_type i = 0; i != x_files.size(); i++) {
    std::string temp = x_files[i];
    std::cout << temp << "\n";
    function(temp);
}
return 0;
}
```

The thing is, as a result I'd like to have this:

```
my_string
Function print: my_string
```

Instead, I get this:

```
my_string
Function print: 0x7cd2346eaf1827cd
```

0x7cd2346eaf1827cd - not exactly what I get every time, but an example.

Comment: just remove the `&` its the adress-of operator. Voting to close as typo

Comment: `std::cout ... << &basicString ...` is printing the address of `basicString`. You may want to remove the `&` and try again.

Comment: In `function()`, your code prints `&basicString`, which is the address in memory of `basicString`.    Remove the `&` to print the contents of `basicString`.

Comment: btw you pass a reference to the function so no copy is made but in `main` you do make a copy `std::string temp = x_files[i];`. C++ uses value semantics. `=` is making a copy

Comment: Everything is now running well, and I've already learned something new with C++. Thanks you all for help! You're the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::cout << "Function print: " << &basicString << "\n";
```

Here you use unary `&` operator, which is an address-of operator, in other words it gives you a pointer. And since this is not a char pointer, `std::cout` prints the pointer value, in other words a memory address, as hex.

Solution is simple, remove `&`:

```
std::cout << "Function print: " << basicString << "\n";
```

---

Perhaps you're getting confused about pointers, because if instead of reference you used a pointer, you'd do this:

```
void function(std::string *basicString) 
{
    std::cout << "Function print: " << *basicString << "\n";
}
```

Pointers and references are quite similar, but they are not the same, including this difference in how they are declared and used.

---

Finally, you probably want to pass a const reference:

```
void function(const std::string &basicString)
```

You should always use `const` with a reference parameter, unless you intend to modify the original.

Answer (score 0):

C++(like many other) is a **context based language**. For example, in you given snippet, when you wrote:

```
void function(std::string &basicString) //here basicString is a lvalue reference to std::string
{

}
```

In the above snippet, you're defining a function named `function` that take one parameter whose type is an *lvalue reference to a `std::string`*. That is, the `&` symbol represents an **lvalue reference** in this context.

On the other hand, when you wrote:

```
std::cout << "Function print: " << &basicString << "\n";
```

Here the `&` symbol means that you're taking the address of the variable to which `basicString` refers.

##### Solution

To **solve** this you just have to remove the `&` symbol as shown below:

```
void function(std::string &basicString) //NO NEED TO REMOVE & FROM HERE
{
std::cout << "Function print: " << basicString << "\n"; //REMOVED & FROM HERE
}
```